# How to get attribute value from HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value from the HTML tag. Not the text itself, but the attribute value. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('label').click(function() {
    $('p').text(($(this).val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label value="hello">click</label>
<p></p>
```

Comment: As a note: `value` isn't valid attributes for [`label`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element). Valid attributes are `for`, the common [Global attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes) and [custom data attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#custom-data-attribute) (`data-*`)

Comment: Use `data-*` it allows you to use any arbitrary string. ex. `data-value="hello"`

Comment: @zer00ne What do you mean use `data-*`? Put it where value is? How would I get the value back in JQuery?

Comment: [jQuery: .data(key)](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key) `[...]Description: Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value) or by an HTML5 data-* attribute.[...]`

Comment: @Jimenemex See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) it allows you to use any arbitrary string. ex. `data-value="hello"`. This is valid and universal on on any element AFAIK. The jQuery method to use is [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
$('label').click(function() {
    $('p').text($(this).data('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label data-value="hello">click</label>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

`labels` don't have `values`, `input` and other `form` elements can have values. So in your case it is jQuery's `attr` function, to receive attribute values. And there is no need of the additional brackets around this getter.

```js
$('label').click(function() {
    $('p').text($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label value="hello">click</label>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do like this in pure JS;

```js
var lab = document.getElementsByTagName("label")[0],
    pel = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
lab.onclick = e => pel.textContent = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("value");
```

```html
<label value="hello">click</label>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('label').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
});
```

Also, I don't think `value` is a valid attribute on a `label` element.

Without jQuery...

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('label')).forEach((label) => {
   label.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let value = label.getAttribute('value');
   });
});
```

Comment: What about a `div`? Does that have a value attribute?

Comment: @Jimenemex They are generally on input elements.

Comment: @Jimenemex no [`div`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-div-element) elements only have [global attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes)